# Android TabHost with ActivityGroup effect without TabHost

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, android-tabhost, activitygroup

I want to create a tab menu similar to TabHost but I would like to use some other elements, not only buttons in that menu, and also be able to bind some other actions than start new activity to buttons.

Basically I need an activity with a layout that I will be able to show in part of every other activity just like TabHost with ActivityGroup. Is it possible at all? Ask me if you didn't understand my idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about using a horizontal scrollview that has a linear layout (with horizontal orientation) , which has all the views that you've mentioned?
beneath it , put a fragment container which can change its content.

if you are unfamiliar with fragments , check the api-demos , or , for "old" versions of android (gingerbread and below) , check the support library demos (v4) .